# Strange error with WCF REST Services

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I have suddenly started facing the below issue.  My REST Service no more works.  It was working sometime ago and I didn't make any changes to config.  As of sudden, it is behaving weird.  I used WCF Test client to check the issue and strangely, the service method gets called 6 times and finally throws the below error.

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from `http://localhost:49796/Test.svc/GetInformation?memberId=1` If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: `http://localhost:49796/Test.svc/GetInformation?memberId=1`    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: '`http://localhost:49796/Test.svc/GetInformation?memberId=1`'.    The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.    The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.HTTP GET Error    URI:

> `http://localhost:49796/Test.svc/GetInformation?memberId=1`

```
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:49796/Test.svc/GetInformation?memberId=1'.    The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.    Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.    An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The most surprising part is that it is same even if I create a new service or test an old service.  Did something went wrong in my pc globally? It appears to be some file corruption or change in config globally somewhere as all of WCF REST Services in my pc behaves the same.  I googled but could not find any proper answer.

I tried removing end point and tested again using Test Client.  As test client adds basichttpbinding automatically, it is working fine using test client.

Please advise on the fix, if anyone is aware.

my config looks like below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="TestService.ServiceLayer.Services.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="TestBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
              contract="TestService.ServiceLayer.Services.ITestService" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
   </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

My Service contract is as below

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetInformation?memberId={memberId}")]
    List<MyTestClass> GetInformation(string memberId);
}
```

I have analyzed further and found that if I change List to string it works fine.  I added KnownType as well on top of service contract but it doesn't work.  Please advise on this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution is mind-blowing.  I see one of the data contract fields is NULL in the DB but it is not Nullable type in C#.  It is resulting in the strange behavior my REST Service.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration, I don't see the Mex binding. Without that, I don't think the Metadata can be obtained from the service. Mex refers to mexHttpBinding

Roughly speaking, it looks something like this:

```
<services>
   <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MEX">
    <endpoint
       address="http://localhost:8000/MEX"
       binding="mexHttpBinding"
       contract="IMetadataExchange"        />
    </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MEX">
        <serviceMetadata/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: I have already added this and tested but of no use.  The main problem I see that it is getting executed 6 times.  Every time I see the correct data is being returned so there is no prob with code.  the only prob with it is something got corrupted which I could not figure out!!

Answer (score 0):

Enable wcf tracing and see the trace log in `SvcTraceViewer.exe`.Check out following link for how to enable trace in wcf.

[4 simple steps to enable tracing in WCF](http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2012/06/simple-steps-to-enable-tracing-in-wcf.html)

**How to use SvcTraceViewer**

[Using Service Trace Viewer for Viewing Correlated Traces and Troubleshooting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751795%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Follow the steps provided in link

Comment: see the service error in  SvcTraceViewer.exe.It will provide the detailed error

Comment: check the location of log file

Comment: I'm now able to generate logs and see something but could not understand the error <MessageLogTraceRecord Time="2014-01-13T22:47:39.3237084+05:30" Source="TransportReceive" Type="System.ServiceModel.Channels.NullMessage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what is problem with your service just by seeing the error message.I have added a link in my answer how to use svctraceviewer utillity

Comment: I tried analyzing the logs.  Every time I hit the REST URL it generates two activities. Each contains "TransportReceive", ServiceLevelReceiveRequest, and ServiceLevelSendReply sources as Information Level.  Does it indicate that every hit resulting in two responses?  Does it mean the service is able to send responses because I see ServiceLevelSendReply has some "stream"?

Comment: I also changed transfermode to buffered but I still don't see the actual message in the reply.  Overall, I could clearly see that I get actual response expected when I put in debug mode before I hit REST URL.  As soon as the service method returns the actual response, I see "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error on the browser.

Comment: It is mad to see the response when I change to ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml from ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json.  Any ideas now to see the actual output for Json?  I was able to view till sometime ago.