# Very strange behaviour of WCF REST Services

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, responseformat

I have designed a REST service with Json response.  It was working fine till yesterday.  Even now, it works if I change ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json to ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml.  Can anyone advise, why as of sudden i'm not abel to get response when I set ResponseFormat to Json?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/Test.svc/GetData?Id=1");
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        string result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The same client works with Xml response but it fails with Json response with the below error.  I started this a couple of weeks and it was working till yesterday. :(

```
    System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at ConsoleTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Sarath\dotNet Samples\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest\Program.cs:line 28
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.IO.IOException
       HResult=-2146232800
       Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
       InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
            HResult=-2147467259
            Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
            Source=System
            ErrorCode=10054
            NativeErrorCode=10054
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
                 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            InnerException:
```

I have further analyzed and found that if I change my return type from List to some type like string. It works fine.  Am I missing something to enable List retrun type for my Json respone?

Comment: This looks like error on the client (caller) side and it doesn't tell much, except the service closed a connection. There should be another exception on service's side. It may be hard to get. I suggest to implement the IErrorHandler (find in internet how exactly). Also it may be configuration issue, if 'the same code' worked before.

Comment: I have further analyzed and found that if I change my return type from List to some type like string. It works fine. Am I missing something to enable List retrun type for my Json respone?  Even I tried placing myclass as return type instead of List, it doesn't work.  If change response format to Xml, anything works.

Comment: The resolution is mind-blowing. I see one of the data contract fields is NULL in the DB but it is not Nullable type in C#. It is resulting in the strange behavior my REST Service.

Comment: Is it a duplicate of your own similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093979/strange-error-with-wcf-rest-services  ?

Comment: unfortunately, yes, as the errors originated were different, i expected to be different issues.  But, at the  end, both resolve to the same fix.